# Storyboard with DiscreteObjectKeyFrame is not working in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, storyboard, blend

I have a storyboard animation in my windows phone 8 app like this one.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="eqAnimation" RepeatBehavior="forever">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="imageEq" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="/Assets/zikzak.png" />
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="/Assets/zikzak2.png" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

but it's not playing at all. I have to change the source of an image control to make a sequential animation.

Comment: what is the code to start the storyboard?

Comment: @kennyzx eqAnimation.Begin();

Comment: Could you show me all your XAML code of your page? I want to know where the Storyboard is defined.

Comment: @kennyzx [link](http://pastebin.com/z0k2NWpT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working snippet, just tested with Windows Phone 8 emulator. You can copy it to your code (update the image paths, of course), to see if it is running.

The Storyboard begins when the page is loaded, not started in code-behind.

```
<Image x:Name="img"> <!--do not set the Source here-->
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="img"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="/Assets/zikzak.png"/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="/Assets/zikzak2.png"/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="/Assets/zikzak.png"/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="/Assets/zikzak2.png"/>

                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Comment: Now the problem is it's always showing only single image all the time.

Comment: @user3134635 Do you set the first DiscreteObjectKeyFrame's KeyTime as "0:0:0.0"? Set it as "0:0:0.01". And do not set the Source of the Image. See me updated code.

Comment: I modified those keytime values. Here is my updated code-[link](http://pastebin.com/MaxChZvR). But still it is just blinking with only one image.

Comment: Yes...I can see what you said about blinking... I add 2 more key frames (just a repetition of the first 2 frames). Now it works, but I don't know why, maybe 2 key frames are too few for the animation to run normally.