# Use multiple pictures to generate a dynamic animation in UWP

Tags: uwp

I use a gif in my UWP project, it will make a dynamic picture. But sometimes I find that the gif dynamic picture will cause some strange broken appearance of the picture. I guess it may be caused by memory issue.

```
 <Image x:Name="voiceBarGif" Opacity="1" 
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/VoiceBar/waveform.gif" />
```

To solve it, I think one solution is to make animation by C# code instead of by gif itself. The first step is to extract pictures from the gif file. In fact, 14 pictures are extracted, and each picture's display time is 0.03s.

[image]

I hope to find a way in UWP to make animation with these 14 picture files and set display time for each one of 0.03s. How?
And I need to make the animation repeatedly, or could be played or stopped via my control.
Thanks!

> **More:**

Thanks to Nico Zhu!
I tried your code, but still failed to show the animation. My code is here:

> git@github.com:tomxue/pictureAnimationInUWP.git

And below.
The second image `img`, I refer to this link:
[Storyboard with DiscreteObjectKeyFrame is not working in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914632/storyboard-with-discreteobjectkeyframe-is-not-working-in-windows-phone-8)

But both codes don't work.

I will try Win2D soon.

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="std" x:Name="std2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="Assets/1.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.06" Value="Assets/2.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.09" Value="Assets/3.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.12" Value="Assets/4.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="Assets/5.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.18" Value="Assets/6.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.21" Value="Assets/7.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.24" Value="Assets/8.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.27" Value="Assets/9.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="Assets/10.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.33" Value="Assets/11.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.36" Value="Assets/12.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.39" Value="Assets/13.png"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.42" Value="Assets/14.png"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Width="500" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image x:Name="img">
            <!--do not set the Source here-->
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="img"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="Assets/1.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.06" Value="Assets/2.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.09" Value="Assets/3.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.12" Value="Assets/4.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="Assets/5.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.18" Value="Assets/6.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.21" Value="Assets/7.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.24" Value="Assets/8.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.27" Value="Assets/9.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="Assets/10.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.33" Value="Assets/11.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.36" Value="Assets/12.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.39" Value="Assets/13.png"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.42" Value="Assets/14.png"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Border>

    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" Width="500" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Image x:Name="image1"/>
    </Border>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="0,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="110" Width="200" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

cs code is below:

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        std2.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Add code, please check my main post.

Comment: This could be solved using Win2D, but could you please upload the gif file somewhere so we can test, or upload a simple repro project on GitHub? If there is a problem with the `Image` control in UWP, it should be fixed.

Comment: This blog may [helpful](http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2016/1/3/gif-rendering-on-winrt-and-uwp).

Comment: @MartinZikmund   I upload my code here: git@github.com:tomxue/pictureAnimationInUWP.git, and you could find the gif file in Assets/wave.gif  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will take a look after work :-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to handle this with code.

1. Change the resource location of bitmapimages from grid to page to make them easier to find.

   ```
   <Page.Resources>
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key1" UriSource="Assets/1.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key2" UriSource="Assets/2.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key3" UriSource="Assets/3.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key4" UriSource="Assets/4.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key5" UriSource="Assets/5.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key6" UriSource="Assets/6.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key7" UriSource="Assets/7.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key8" UriSource="Assets/8.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key9" UriSource="Assets/9.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key10" UriSource="Assets/10.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key11" UriSource="Assets/11.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key12" UriSource="Assets/12.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key13" UriSource="Assets/13.png" />
   <BitmapImage x:Key="key14" UriSource="Assets/14.png" /> </Page.Resources>
   ```
2. Edit the click event.

   ```
       int index = 0;
       while(true)
       {
           index++;
           var bitmap = this.Resources[$"key{index}"] as BitmapImage;
           image1.Source = bitmap;
           await Task.Delay(30);
           if (index == 14)
               index = 0;
       }
   ```

When running, the first few seconds of flickering appear to be due to the time it takes to load the image.
I think this problem will be solved by reading the image ahead of time in the code and creating it as a BitmapImage.

Comment: Thank you! This method works fine, although it has the issue as you have mentioned. I will try to improve it as you suggested.